# Visio Question? Is there a way to set the property of something to Always be in Front?

Tags: properties, visio

So you can arrange items to be in the back or front, is there a way to set it to always be Front?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot set an object to be always in front.  You can select an object, right click, choose the Shape option (or the Shape menu from the menu bar) and select "Bring to Front" to move that object to the front, but if you add another object, it will be on top of the first object until you do the "Bring to Front" on the first object again.

Just think if there were a property to set for "Always in front", what would happen if you set it to true on two objects and then attempted to put one over the other?  See Raymond Chen's post ["What if two programs did this?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx).  The scenario of two Visio objects doesn't have as much potential negative consequences, but could still cause issues.  Even if it only allowed one object to be the "always in front", it would be a lot of complexity for little gain.